# Definition indepedence and identically distributed (iid)

Tags: probability, distributions, econometrics, random-variable, independence

Bruce Hansen's book "Econometrics" defines a random sample as follows:
"The observations $(y_i,x_i, z_i)$ are a random sample if they are mutually independent and identically distributed $(iid)$ across $i =1, ..., n.$"

I have two questions about this definition: $1)$ Can two observations be iid or does the concept of iid apply only to random variables? In other words, each observation must be associated with a random variable. And the different observations correspond to the result of the same experiment.
$2)$ Since each observation is made up of three elements $(y_i, x_i, z_i)$, then should each observation be considered as the realization of a random vector? So the concept of iid refers here to the independence and identical distribution of random vectors and not random variables?

Comment: I would assume that each observation was a triplet, and so the realisation of a random variable (in $\mathbb R^3$ or whatever - if it helps to call this triplet a random vector, then you can do so but it is also a random variable). The sample is $n$ such realisations, mutually i.i.d.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both [independence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independence_(probability_theory)) and having a [distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_distribution) are properties that can be possessed only by random variables. In your example $y_i, x_i,z_i$ is a random vector, where for each $i$ they jointly have identical distribution and are independent of other such triplets. What we mean by such definition is that we *treat* the observations as realizations of the random variables.

Comment: Does the concept of independence apply between random vectors?

Comment: @JuanBromas multivariate random variable is a random variable, so it has all the properties random variables have, and same laws of probability apply to it.